# Instance <xxx> has been deleted after commit(), but when and why?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Here's a really simple piece of code. After adding the "poll" instance to the DB and committing, I cannot later read it. SQLAlchemy fails with the error:

```
Instance '<PollStat at 0x7f9372ea72b0>' has been deleted, or its row is otherwise not present.
```

Weirdly, this does not happen if I replace the ts_start/ts_run primary key by an integer autoincrement one. Is it possible that DateTime columns are not suitable as primary key?

```
db = Session()
poll = models.PollStat(
    ts_start=datetime.datetime.now(),
    ts_run=ts_run,
    polled_tools=0)
db.add(poll)
db.commit()              # I want to commit here in case something fails later
print(poll.polled_tools) # this fails
```

PollStat in module models.py:

```
class PollStat(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'poll_stat'
    ts_run        = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    ts_start      = Column(DateTime, primary_key=True)
    elapsed_ms    = Column(Integer, default=None)
    polled_tools  = Column(Integer, default=0)
```

But if I do this:

```
class PollStat(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'poll_stat'
    id            = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    ts_run        = Column(Integer)
    ts_start      = Column(DateTime)
    elapsed_ms    = Column(Integer, default=None)
    polled_tools  = Column(Integer, default=0)
```

it works. Why?

Comment: What dialect and dbapi provider are you using? In other words, what does your connection URI start with (e.g., something like `mssql+pyodbc`)?

Comment: It does boil down to the `datetime` being stored in a way that prevents retrieving the row after the commit.

Comment: It's mysql://. And Ilja is probably right about the DateTime. Maybe some time I'll try and see if there's anything in the docs about this. Funny that sqlalchemy doesn't emit a warning though.

Comment: At least in MariaDB, the datetime is truncated to _seconds_ precision in the database, as Ilja suggested.  The session tracks objects using their primary keys, so the session and database state no longer match, and SQLAlchemy assumes the row has been deleted when it can't match the session values with the database.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that still has this problem, this error happened to me because I submitted a JSON object with an `id` of 0; I use the same form for adding and editing said object, so when editing this would normally have an ID number, but when creating the item, the id property needs to be deleted before inserting the item. Some databases don't accept an ID of 0. In the end the row is created but the ID of 0 no longer matches the current ID, hence why the error pops up.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason can be that 2 fields are defined as Primary Keys in SQLAlchemy.

I had the following code in SQLModel, which rides over SQLAlchemy. On Insert of new data, the model object showed the same error and failed to refresh.

```
def create_data(data: DataSqlModel,
                           session: Session = Depends(EngineSession.get_session)):
    session.add(data)
    try:
        session.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))
    session.refresh(data)
    return data
```

The reason was that the model had 2 primary keys, as follows:

```
class DataSqlModel(SQLModel, table=True):
    __tablename__ = 'data'

    id: Optional[int] = Field(primary_key=True, index=True, nullable=False)
    unique_name: UUID = Field(primary_key=True, index=True, nullable=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

The real reason turned out to be something different: The datetime.datetime.now() produces a value with fractional seconds (which is also used in the session cache). By committing the "poll" instance, the ts_start property is rounded to full seconds, which is why the session can't find it any more.